# How to get the year when bolding month days in a TMonthCalendar?

Tags: delphi, calendar, delphi-2009

I have a log that use the Calendar and I want to bold the days that have recorded info. I have them in an 3D array `TDiaryLog = array[1900..2399] of array[1..12] of array[1..31] of POneDay;`. But in the `OnGetMonthInfo`, when I must build the list with the bold days, it gives me only the `Month`, and not the Year. How should I know for what month I must pass the day if I don't have the year ? When December is displayed as the current month in the Calendar, there are a few days shown from the January next year !

```
procedure TMainForm.CalendarGetMonthInfo(Sender: TObject; Month: Cardinal;
  var MonthBoldInfo: Cardinal);
begin
end;
```

Comment: That is a TMonthCalendar not a TCalendar.  You can get it from the current date set but it seems to sometimes lag what is navigated to.

Comment: `OnGetMonthInfo` event is triggered 3 times for every month change. One for the current date an the others two for the month before and after. And I cannot know which is the current one...

Comment: The date looks to be the same for all three calls but might be usable to compare with the month given to figure out the year. `memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Month)+ ' ' + DateTimeToStr(MonthCalendar1.Date));`

Comment: Use OnMonthGetBoldInfo instead, which passes the year as well as the month. Does it exist in D2009?

Comment: @Sertac, no, Delphi 2009 doesn't. The OP will need to listen to the `MCN_GETDAYSTATE` notification and read the starting date by themselves.

Comment: Thanks @TLama. Unfortunately it would seem so, OnGetMonthInfo is ultimately useless if you need the year, which would be the case if you're doing something a little more complicated than the example in the docs - which bolds day 1 and 8 of every month!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a new component where I intercepted the `MCN_GETDAYSTATE` message and I extracted the year too from the message info... It was there all the time, but Delphi decided that year is not useful.

```
  TOnGetMonthInfoExEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Year, Month: Word;
    var MonthBoldInfo: LongWord) of object;

  TNewMonthCalendar = class(TMonthCalendar)
  private
    FOnGetMonthInfoEx: TOnGetMonthInfoExEvent;
    procedure CNNotify(var Msg: TWMNotifyMC); message CN_NOTIFY;
  published
    property OnGetMonthInfoEx: TOnGetMonthInfoExEvent read FOnGetMonthInfoEx write FOnGetMonthInfoEx;
  end;

procedure TNewMonthCalendar.CNNotify(var Msg: TWMNotifyMC);
var
  I: Integer;
  Month, Year: Word;
  DS: PNMDayState;
  CurState: PMonthDayState;
begin
 if (Msg.NMHdr.code = MCN_GETDAYSTATE) and Assigned(FOnGetMonthInfoEx) then begin
  DS:= Msg.NMDayState;
  FillChar(DS.prgDayState^, DS.cDayState * SizeOf(TMonthDayState), 0);
  CurState:= DS.prgDayState;
  for I:= 0 to DS.cDayState - 1 do begin
   Year:= DS.stStart.wYear;
   Month:= DS.stStart.wMonth + I;
   if Month > 12 then begin Inc(Year); Dec(Month, 12); end;
   FOnGetMonthInfoEx(Self, Year, Month, CurState^);
   Inc(CurState);
  end;
 end
 else inherited;
end;
```

**BONUS**

And, as a bonus, you need this to update the changes you made to the bold info of the current month view... because it doesn't work with `Invalidate`.

```
procedure TNewMonthCalendar.RefreshDayState;
var N: Cardinal;
    Range: array[0..1] of TSystemTime;
    Year, Month: Word;
    States: array of TMonthDayState;
    I: Integer;
begin
 if not Assigned(FOnGetMonthInfoEx) then Exit;
 N:= SendMessage(Handle, MCM_GETMONTHRANGE, GMR_DAYSTATE, LPARAM(@Range));
 Year:= Range[0].wYear;
 Month:= Range[0].wMonth;
 SetLength(States, N);
 FillChar(States[0], N * SizeOf(TMonthDayState), 0);
 for I:= 0 to N-1 do begin
  FOnGetMonthInfoEx(Self, Year, Month, States[I]);
  Inc(Month);
  if Month > 12 then
   begin Dec(Month, 12); Inc(Year); end;
 end;
 SendMessage(Handle, MCM_SETDAYSTATE, N, LPARAM(@States[0]));
end;
```

Comment: That's why they introduced new event `OnMonthGetBoldInfo` later on.